Cannot write data into a CnosDB v2.4.1 Cluster
I deployed a CnosDB (v2.4.0 revision 48ea218) with three servers, each having a data node, and one of them also has a meta node.
The write method is as follows:
curl -XPOST -u "root:" "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=public" -d "ma,ta=a fa=1i"

The error message is as follows:
error： 050019， error_message: grpc client request error: The Operation can only Exec in Leader ReplicationSet {id: 38, leader_node_id 15, leader_vnode_id:39 vnodes: [VnodeInfo {id: 39, node_id:15, status: Running }]}

Since I has just one meta and that should be the leader. I am running the write POST request on that node. How do I resolve this?
More info added below:
OS: Red Hat enterpriseLinuxServerrelease7.9 Beta（Maipo）
Linux xxx02 3.10.0-1136.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 17 11:40:59 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
CPU: 24
Memory: 64G
Disk: HDD 500GB

Hello, I tested it locally according to your version and your deployment method, and found no problems. Can you add some details?My environment here is as follows: OS:Linux ubuntu20 5.4.0-172-generic #190-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 2 23:24:22 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  cnosdb: 48ea2181f6564ec727508a6177a893d6c9bf4fe4.    deploy:1meta+3querytskv

@BakerX thx for the help. more info added.
